# Regex which only allows numbers in a interval in discrete steps

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression which only allows numbers in an interval `from 100 to 2000`, with steps of 10.

```
- It must accept numbers like 100, 110, 120,...1990, 2000. 
 - It must avoid numbers like 90, 123,..., 1945, 2010.
```

Comment: Well based on what I found on this forum: ^[0-9]*$ But just the beginning of the puzzle.

Comment: Why not try to implement it than? Go step by step and you will achieve it.

Comment: Remember that regexes are for matching patterns, not testing numerical values.  You may need to use a regex to find strings that match a pattern, but then compare the values of those strings with your host language.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
^(?:[1-9]\d0|1\d{2}0|2000)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aI0fO8/2)

Comment: @borisbn Thanks for noticing the bug ;)